# App not retrieving data from Azure mobile service table

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

Well my android app has trouble getting data from a table in my mobile service.

It connects to the azure mobile service server using the MobileserviceClient with no errors what so ever. But when i try to get a table and take the data out of that table that app freezes on that 1 line and gives me a white screen.

So some help would be great cause I have no clue what I am doing wrong. Also there is already 50 rows of data in the restaurantdata table.

```
private MobileServiceClient mClient;
private MobileServiceTable<RestaurantData> table;
private MobileServiceList<RestaurantData> list;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activityMainToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.activityMainCoordinatorLayout);
    viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_new_restaurants, viewGroup, false);
    coordinatorLayout.addView(view);       

    try {
        Log.e("Log", "Log1");
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient("Service doamin", "application key here", getApplicationContext());
        Log.e("Log", "Log2");
        table = mClient.getTable(RestaurantData.class);
        Log.e("Log", "Log3");
        list = table.execute().get();//App freezes here with white screen
        Log.e("Log", "Log4");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERROR2", " " + e);
    }
    Log.e("Log", "Log6");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your code snippet you provided, it seems you just get the data via `list = table.execute().get()` but do not present your data to the view.

Usually, we can leverage [list view](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) and [adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) to present our data in list.

Here are the code snippet on Azure Mobile Service Android Client sample:

```
public class ToDoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem> {

/**
 * Adapter context
 */
Context mContext;

/**
 * Adapter View layout
 */
int mLayoutResourceId;

public ToDoItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId);

    mContext = context;
    mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
}

/**
 * Returns the view for a specific item on the list
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    final ToDoItem currentItem = getItem(position);

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    row.setTag(currentItem);

    return row;
}
```

}

**define variables :**

```
private ToDoItemAdapter mAdapter;


mAdapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row_list_to_do);
ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**add list item in listview:**

```
for (ToDoItem item : list) {
    mAdapter.add(item);
}
```

Comment: The code does not pass the point where I grab the data from the table. So there would be no point of trying to set it to an adapter if the code does not pass that point.

Comment: So you mean there are something wrong when you query the data? Do you get any error message in android? And is there any error logs in your mobile service manage portal in **LOGS** tab?

Comment: Yea, cause I've placed Android log tags in so see the exact place where the error is made. And the logs don't go past log 3 in the code given above.

Comment: Do you have any detailed logs? It seems you occurred some issue when your app run at `table = mClient.getTable(RestaurantData.class);`, do you have created the table named `RestaurantData`  in Azure SQL which is associated to your mobile service

Comment: Yes so the Table is created with colums and data inserted and everything. Would you be able to explain how to get the new logs the way you want it, as I have migrated this over the new App service and Im still trying to find everything there. Thanks

Comment: Also using the same mclient details i can insert data into the table with no worries. No errors nothing app work like a charm.

Comment: OK, so you occurred the issue when your app querying database. Could you please login https://manage.windowsazure.com in the manage page of your mobile service, click **LOGS** tab, is there any error logs?

Comment: There is no logs tab. This was a mobile service which was migrated over to the new app service in the new portal.

Comment: Update, getting data from any table in the database does not work.

Comment: Update recreating tables does not work, now recreating database entirely.

Comment: Update recreating database did not fix. recreated mobile service still did not fix.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I had reported this issue and we will get back to you later as soon as we can. 
Appreciate your understanding.

Comment: It seems to be the '.get' method on the end to get the final table results into a list.

Comment: Try turning on streaming logs. Once you have the streaming logs view up, run your app and if there is a server error occuring you should see the details in the log stream. Info on how to turn it on is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-streaming-logs-and-console/