# Azure Mobile app get method android freezes app

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have decent background of azure mobile apps, but not on the android side.

and also complete java beginner.

Today, I am trying my hands at it, with azure mobile app running locally .

It has table controller with simple todotable with 1 column "Name"

and this is my code.

```
public class TodoItem {
   private String Id;
   private String Name;
}

private void CreateMobileAppClient() {

   String mobileAppUrl="http://localhost:58441/";
   try {
       mobileServiceClient = new MobileServiceClient(new URL(mobileAppUrl), this);
   } catch(IOException e){
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
}

private void GetData() {

    MobileServiceTable<TodoItem>   mTable=mobileServiceClient.getTable(TodoItem.class);
    try {
        List<TodoItem> results = mTable.execute().get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Log.d("debug","data success");
        String str="";
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

During debugging all is okay, till I get to `execute().get()` method.

At this point my app completely freezes, neither goes in catch block, nor goes to next line .

I don't see much in logs and messages either.

I think the question is similar to this one 
[App not retrieving data from Azure mobile service table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346425/app-not-retrieving-data-from-azure-mobile-service-table)

Any help would be useful.

(P.S: table controller on the azure side, works perfect with fiddler, so no problems there.)

Comment: DO you get anything if you add a log statement to your backend in the GetAll method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
MobileServiceList<TodoItem> results = mTable.execute().get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Also you should get those results in an `AsyncTask`.

```
private void GetData()
    {

    MobileServiceTable<TodoItem> mTable = mobileServiceClient.getTable(TodoItem.class);
    MobileServiceList<TodoItem> results;

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
             try {
                 results = mTable.execute().get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                 Log.d("debug","data success");
                 }
             catch(Exception e)
                 {

                 }
            return null;
           }
       }.execute();
    }
```